# Swift Decoding Error - ( suspect: Some Field Sometime Empty)

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

If I remove variable `options` the code will work, but I need it. I think the problem is because options array may/can empty.

**Model**

```swift
struct Schedule: Codable {
    let batch: String
    let menu: SubSchedule?
}

struct SubSchedule: Codable {
    let name: String
    let price: Int

    let options: [Options]?  //  <--- If I remove this, it'll work
}

struct Options: Codable {
    let field: String?
    let options: [SubOption]?
}

struct SubOption: Codable {
    let _id: String
    let addPrice: Int
    let value: String
}
```

**Service**

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
    let result = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])

    print(result as Any) // print decoded json

    let schedules = try!
                JSONDecoder().decode([Schedule].self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    completion(schedules)
                }
    }.resume()
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "batch": "Lunch",
    "menu": {
        "name": "Dailysuki Tomyam Soup",
        "options": [{
            "field": "Tambah Nasi",
            "options": [{
                "addPrice": 0,
                "value": "None"
            }]
        }],

        // options not always have a value (may empty)
        //
        // options: ['']
        //

        "price": 25000
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "menu", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "options", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file /PROJECT/Services/Webservices.swift, line 23
```

Comment: If you remove `let options: [SubOption]?`, is your code working ?

Comment: No. the error is `Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the `_id` variable in your `SubOption` struct to optional and tell me if it works

```
struct SubOption: Codable {
    let _id: String?
    let addPrice: Int
    let value: String
}
```

Comment: oh god , sorry its not a JSON. I got that from xcode console after decoded, I will change it.

Comment: you can see it now

Comment: `Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: @dhidy I really need to see your JSON in order to help you

Comment: thank for your direction, now I know where the problem is. 'options' property in my JSON have an array with empty string value.

`options: [ '' ]` not empty array `options: [ ]`.

but I still I don't know how to change it (if `options: ['']` change to `options: []` as default)